# How do I report fraud or App Store rule violations outside of a refund context?

Tags: ios-appstore

I'm not a developer, and I already used the "reportaproblem" link which doesn't help. It specifically hides any purchases made before the last 90 days.

I already read [How to report App Store rule violations?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88508/how-to-report-app-store-rule-violations) and that didn't help one bit.

In particular, I want to report an app for an App Store rules violation and it appears that Apple blocked off all standard support routes to save money or something. In this case, the rules violation happened in an update years after purchase (so reportaproblem doesn't apply).

Comment: What makes you believe that Apple didn‘t react on your initial report? Maybe they did, and found the app not be in violation of the rules (there is a difference about pushing in-app purchases versus real-life stuff maybe)? Anyway, asking basically the same question again won‘t yield any better answers. If you are open for alternative routes reaching out to a consumer rights group in your country or a journalist might be options.

Comment: I never got the chance to make an initial report, because Apple's reporting options make it virtually impossible to report anything other than a 90-day purchase problem.

Answer (score 2):

Fraud should be easy - engage a lawyer and/or your local small claims court. If the fraud is contract based, monetary remedy Is likely from small claims court in your jurisdiction at little expense to you in time or legal fees.

For wanting to police Apple and/or developers on what you find to be in violation of Apple policies but not actual laws, I stand by [my answer to the question you linked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/88679/5472).

- Unless you have a developer relation and another developer is infringing on your work, you (the consumer) can only really ask Apple for a refund or just delete the app and send them general feedback when the report site has an explicit 90 time limit documented.

If you feel you have an exceptionally serious issue, why not engage store support chat to validate how Apple would want to hear about the specifics?

- https://support.apple.com/contact

Comment: Like I previously said, your answer in that link does not by any means fit my question. I don't know why people are so hell-bent on insisting that people accept what has already been outed as unfit for the question. Also ironic that the App Store supposedly has rules, with no way to report rule violations.

Comment: What people are hell bent? There are multiple avenues to report rule violations. Are you bringing some expectations or frustration from real life into this space? See my edit above if your comment was while I was editing my answer here @user1258361